# What all should I be optimizing based on MySQL Tuner results?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, query-performance, mysqltuner

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Log file: /var/log/mysqld.log(4K)

[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log exists

[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is readable.

[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is not empty

[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is smaller than 32 Mb

[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 21 warning(s).

[OK] /var/log/mysqld.log doesn't contain any error.

[--] 3 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log

[--] 1) 170307 19:53:17 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.

[--] 2) 170307 19:50:51 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.

[--] 3) 170307 19:47:30 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.

[--] 3 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log

[--] 1) 170307 19:53:17 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

[--] 2) 170307 19:50:51 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

[--] 3) 170307 19:47:29 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Status: +CSV +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM

[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 33M (Tables: 29)

[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 368M (Tables: 52)

[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------

---

---

[!!] User '@jobzmachine' is an anonymous account.

[!!] User '@localhost' is an anonymous account.

[!!] User '@jobzmachine' has no password set.

[!!] User '@localhost' has no password set.

[!!] User '@jobzmachine' has user name as password.

[!!] User '@localhost' has user name as password.

[!!] User 'backup@%' hasn't specific host restriction.

[!!] User 'search@%' hasn't specific host restriction.

[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations ------------------------------

---

--

[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Up for: 3m 12s (23K q [123.125 qps], 133 conn, TX: 77M, RX: 2M)

[--] Reads / Writes: 84% / 16%

[--] Binary logging is disabled

[--] Physical Memory : 31.2G

[--] Max MySQL memory : 1.6G

[--] Other process memory: 2.3G

[--] Total buffers: 1.2G global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)

[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B

[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B

[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.4G (4.61% of installed RAM)

[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.6G (5.04% of installed RAM)

[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available

[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/23K)

[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 66% (101/151)

[!!] Aborted connections: 13.53% (18/133)

[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.

[OK] Query cache efficiency: 78.2% (11K cached / 15K selects)

[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0

[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 505 sorts)

[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 1

[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 48% (142 on disk / 292 total)

[!!] Thread cache hit rate: 24% (101 created / 133 connections)

[OK] Table cache hit rate: 88% (56 open / 63 opened)

[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (17/1K)

[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (5K immediate / 5K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Performance schema is disabled.

[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B

[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)

[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/20.6M

[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (393K cached / 0 reads)

[OK] Write Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (1K cached / 0 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] InnoDB is enabled.

[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 8

[!!] InnoDB File per table is not activated

[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 1.0G/368.2M

[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (0.9765625 %): 5.0M * 2/1.0G should be equal 25%

[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version

[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.95% (5772058 hits/ 5774714 total)

[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 77.58% (256 hits/ 330 total)

[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 586 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics ------------------------------

---

---

[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO

[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.

[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ------------------------------

---

---

General recommendations:

Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysqld.log file

Remove Anonymous User accounts - there are 2 anonymous accounts.

Set up a Password for user with the following SQL statement ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )

Set up a Secure Password for user@host ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )

Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp

MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate

Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues

Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes

When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_

size equal

Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause

Performance shouldn't be activated for MySQL and MariaDB 5.5 and lower version

Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys

Variables to adjust:

query_cache_type (=0)

join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)

tmp_table_size (> 32M)

max_heap_table_size (> 32M)

thread_cache_size (> 16384)

performance_schema = OFF disable PFS

innodb_file_per_table=ON

innodb_log_file_size * innodb_log_files_in_group should be equals to 1/4 of buffer pool size (=512M) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate

Up only 3 minutes!  Not enough time for gathering much useful info.

But, usually you cannot "tune away performance problems".  If you have slow queries, let's see them, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant table(s).

> [OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 1.0G/368.2M

You have a rather small dataset; do you expect it to grow?

Your `GRANTs` make it easy for a hacker to take over your computer.

The rest of the recommendations are mostly minor -- so far.

Answer (score 0):

in your .cfg/.ini

```
thread_cache_size = 100    Current suggested cap to avoid thread creation thrashing.   NOT >16384 as suggested by tuner.
```

Need a MySQLTUNER after 24 hours uptime for more meaningful analysis/results.